# Minkowski inequality

Tags: real-analysis

In the Wikipedia proof of the Minkowski inequality (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality), the following inequality is used:
$$|f+g|^p\leq2^{p-1}(|f|^p+|g|^p).$$
I was just wondering if this inequality has a name or if this is too "first principles" to warrant a name.

Thanks!

Comment: If I read the article correctly it's just using convexity.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I was under the impression that this was generally true!

Comment: It is generally true. It is the composition of the triangle inequality |f+g| </= |f|+|g| composed with the power mean inequality (a+b)/2 </= ((a^p+b^p)/2)^(1/p) for a=|f| and b=|g| which is a consequence of convexity.

Answer (score 7):

It is not named after a person, but I would argue that the inequality does have a name, "the convexity inequality for x<sup>p</sup>".  If you look at the definition of [a convex function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function), the statement that f(x) = x<sup>p</sup> is convex is exactly the statement that ((x+y)/2)<sup>p</sup> ≤ (x<sup>p</sup>+y<sup>p</sup>)/2. (Plus either that f is continuous or that the weighted version also holds).  It is also correct to say "is a consequence of convexity", but it seems better to call it the statement of convexity than a consequence of convexity.

The multivariate form of the convexity inequality is named after a person; it is [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

All of this may seem like a pat answer, but it works.  It is a theorem that you get a valid norm if x<sup>p</sup> is replaced by any non-negative convex function φ(x) with suitable behavior at 0 and ∞.  The resulting norm is called an Orlicz norm and the resulting Banach space is called an [Orlicz space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlicz_space).